# Maintaining $_SESSION data while making ajax requests through jquery in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session-cookies, gdata

I'm on the last leg of a decent project (for me at least) and I'm running into an issue where my ajax requests aren't sending $_SESSION data to the URLs they are loading.  I'm trying to automate the upload of files you YouTube, using Gdata.  I make an ajax request using jquery but when I test for $_SESSION['sessionToken'] in my ajax called PHP script, I get nothing.

Here's my code, that's calling the YouTube upload script:

```
function uploadVideos(id, upload, selected) {
        var status = document.getElementById('currentStatus');
        var fields = upload[id].split(":", 2);

        var token="<?php echo $_GET['token'];?>";
        var dataString = 'videoId='+ fields[0]; // + '&token=' + token;

        id++;
        status.innerHTML = "<b>Videos for Upload:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <h3 class='status'>Currently Updating Bout #" + fields[1] + " (" + id + " of " + upload.length + " videos)</h3>";

        $.ajax({  
            type: "GET",  
            url: "upload.php",  
            data: dataString,
            success: function(txt) {
                if (txt != 'Success') {
                    alert(txt);
                } 

                if (id < upload.length) {
                    uploadVideos(id, upload, selected);

                } else {

                    status.innerHTML = "<b>Videos for Upload:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <h3 class='status'>Completed</h3>";
                }

                //deselect the checkbox
                document.videos.video[selected[id-1]].checked = false;
                document.videos.video[selected[id-1]].style.display = 'none';
            },
            async: true

        }); 
}
```

How can I send sessionToken along to upload.php, to it believes I'm authenticated?

Comment: I probably included more code here that is really useful.  I basically just want a way to add something like "session: sessionString" to the .ajax request.

Comment: Just in case it's not clear, anything in $_SESSION is only on the server and not on the client. You need to make sure that the token is being send from the browser, typically via a cookie.

Comment: I know I have the cookie.  I can echo "$_SESSION['sessionToken'] on my script that I included, and I see the value of the token.  I want to put that value in the header of my ajax request too, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: If you have the token on your session you don't have to send it through the ajax request.  The only token you have to send is PHPSESSID, and the browser automatically does that (using a cookie).  That sessid is internally used by PHP to load all your session variables (including your "sessionToken") on every execution, no matter if it's an ajax call or a regular request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First:**
You are not sending the "token"-variable with your Ajax call. You are sending the variable dataString which does not include the token variable. You have commented the token part out...

```
var token="<?php echo $_GET['token'];?>"; 
var dataString = 'videoId='+ fields[0]; // + '&token=' + token;
```

**Second:**
You can only send Ajax with POST or GET

in your ajax call you are using GET, so you should check for $_GET; Not $_SESSION.

Comment: I have the GET token commented out, because it's a one time use token per Gdata.  I can get that to work for one upload, but subsequent uploads will fail.  You can see that my uploadVideos() function is recursive, so I need to be able to call it multiple times.  Gdata requires the use of a session token to make that happen.  My requests are still either GET or POST (GET in this case) but I should be able to set the cookie. Right?

Comment: try to call session_start() in your upload.php before reading from $_SESSION

Comment: Ya. I agree with @Christian. Did you remember to call session_start() in all the places that needs to access the session? Ajax should still send the session id back as it is the browser calling your scripts.

Comment: Christian got it!  Once I set started the session, it worked perfectly.  Thanks!